# AngularJS + CanvasJS: how to unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, canvasjs

I'm tring to run unit tests in an AngularJS application scaffolded using Yeoman.
The only test I'm trying to run just check if and array has correct length but fails 
because of something related to CanvasJS

Here the LOG

```
LOG: 'CanvasJS Error: Chart Container with id "chartContainer" was not found'
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of inputs to the scope  FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this._toolBar.appendChild')
            at /path/to/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:1799
            at /path/to/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:1919
            at /path/to/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:2093
            at /path/to/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:12551
            at /path/to/Chart/app/scripts/controllers/main.js:101
            at invoke (/path/to/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869)
            at instantiate (/path/to/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3880)
            at /path/to/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7134
            at /path/to/Chart/test/spec/controllers/main.js:15
            at invoke (/path/to/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869)
            at workFn (/path/to/Chart/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2147)
        undefined
        Expected 0 to be 3.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.025 secs / 0.021 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

The application can be found here https://github.com/kaiohken1982/Chart

I'm not sure if I have implemented right this library within the AngularJS app, advices will be very appreciated.

Thanks

------------------- EDIT #1 --------------------

Here below some code to make understanding better the scenario, as you can see CanvasJS is 
used as global not injected as a service, so one of the question is if it is correct to use a third party library this way if there's not a bower repo.

This line I think is causing the issue

```
...
$scope.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
...
```

The controller view contains the "chartContainer" id

```
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

app/scripts/controllers/main.js
    'use strict';

```
/*global CanvasJS:false */

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name ngprojectApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the ngprojectApp
 */
angular.module('ChartApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // Regexp to ensure that input dates are in the required format
    $scope.dateRegexp = /^(January|February|March|April|June|July|August|Semptember|October|November|December)[ ](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[ ](19|20)\d{2}$/i;

    // Called to remove an entry
    $scope.removeInput = function (index) {
      $scope.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    };

    // Called to add an entry
    $scope.addRow = function () {
      $scope.inputs.push($scope.value);
      $scope.value = '';
    };

     $scope.predicate = '';
     $scope.reverse = false;
     $scope.inputs = [];
     $scope.updateMyText = function() {};

     // Chart below
     var datapoints = [];

     var chartPoint = null;
     $scope.canEdit = true;
     $scope.editMode = false;
     $scope.units = 1; // increase or decrease bar value by this unit
     $scope.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
       theme: 'theme1',
       interactivityEnabled: true,
       title:{
          text: 'Website response time'              
       },
       axisY: {
          title: 'ms',
          labelFontSize: 16,
       },
       axisX: {
          title: 'timeline',
          labelFontSize: 16,
          gridThickness: 1
       },
       data: [              
          {
            click: function() {
              $scope.$apply(function() {
                if($scope.canEdit) {
                  $scope.editMode = !$scope.editMode; 
                }
              });

              if($scope.editMode) {
                console.log('EditMode is now TRUE');
              }

              if(!$scope.editMode) {
                console.log('EditMode is now FALSE');
              }
            },
            mousemove: function(e) {
              if(!$scope.editMode) {
                chartPoint = null;
                return false;
              }

              // First point? Assign it and return
              if(null === chartPoint) {
                chartPoint = e;
                return false;
              }

              // Update inputs at the correct index will re-render graph and table data
              $scope.$apply(function() {
                var diffY = e.y - chartPoint.y; // if it is > 0 means that the mouse pointer went UP
                var time = diffY < 0 ? e.dataPoint.y+$scope.units : e.dataPoint.y-$scope.units;
                $scope.inputs[e.dataPointIndex].time = time;
                // Update chartPoint
                chartPoint = e;
              });

            },
             type: 'column',
             dataPoints: []
          }
       ]
    });

    $scope.chart.render(); //render the chart for the first time

    $scope.changeChartType = function(chartType) {
      $scope.canEdit = 'column' === chartType;
      $scope.editMode = false; // disable EditMode whatever the type is
      $scope.chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = datapoints;
      $scope.chart.options.data[0].type = chartType;
        $scope.chart.render(); //re-render the chart to display the new layout
    };

    // DEEP watch for any changes in the array
    $scope.$watch('inputs', function() {
      datapoints = [];
      for(var i in $scope.inputs) {
        var e = $scope.inputs[i];
        // update the timestamp for the value
        var d = new Date(e.date);
        e.timestamp = d.valueOf() / 1000;
        datapoints.push({
          'label': e.url,
          x: new Date(e.date),
          y: e.time
        });
      }
      // Reassign data to chart
      $scope.chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = datapoints;
      $scope.chart.render();
    }, true);


    $scope.inputs.push({
      date: 'January 02 2014',
      url: 'http://uno.it',
      time: 111
    });

    $scope.inputs.push({
      date: 'January 12 2014',
      url: 'http://due.it',
      time: 292
    });

    $scope.inputs.push({
      date: 'January 22 2014',
      url: 'http://tre.it',
      time: 333
    });

  });
```

test/spec/controllers/main.js
    'use strict';

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('ChartApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of inputs to the scope ', function () {
    expect(scope.inputs.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Karma.conf.js has all required files, I suppose...

```
....
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',

      'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js',
      'app/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
      'app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/canvasjs.min.js',

      'app/scripts/directives/directive.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
...
```

------------------- EDIT #2 --------------------

This is how I've edited the main.js test after the advices received

```
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $compile) {
    var htmlString = '' +
    '<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">' +
    '    <div id="chartContainer">' +
    '</div>'
    ;
    var element = angular.element(htmlString)
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));
```

The error is almost the same

```
LOG: 'CanvasJS Error: Chart Container with id "chartContainer" was not found'
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of inputs to the scope  FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this._toolBar.appendChild')
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:1799
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:1919
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:2093
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/scripts/vendor/canvasjs-1.5.0-beta/source/canvasjs.js:12551
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/scripts/controllers/main.js:101
            at invoke (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869)
            at instantiate (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3880)
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7134
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6538
            at forEach (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330)
            at nodeLinkFn (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6552)
            at compositeLinkFn (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5986)
            at publicLinkFn (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5891)
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/test/spec/controllers/main.js:20
            at invoke (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869)
            at workFn (/path/to/workspace/Chart/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2147)
        undefined
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.inputs.length')
            at /path/to/workspace/Chart/test/spec/controllers/main.js:28
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.029 secs / 0.028 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Did I mistake something when update the test controller?

------------------- EDIT #3 --------------------

With the precious help of Ivarni I've ended up with this solution:

In the application controller

```
...
$scope.chart = new $window.CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
...
```

In the controller test

```
...
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $compile, $window) {
    $window.CanvasJS = { Chart: function(){
        this.render = function() {};
    } };
...
```

CanvasJS is now mocked and UnitTest can run :)

Comment: Hi, I've added the whole main controller, its tests and the configuration of Karma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your assumption about what's causing the error is correct. Your controller is not attached to a DOM so it's reasonable that it's not being able to locate anything with an id "chartContainer".

For unit testing this I would try the same approach as I would use to unit test a directive.
That is something along the lines of

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var htmlString = '' +
        '<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">' +
        '    <div id="chartContainer">' +
        '</div>'
        ;
    element = angular.element(htmlString)
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));
```

This compiles a minimal piece of DOM with your controller attached and an element with the id required by CanvasJS. You'll probably have to fiddle a bit more with that. I don't see a problem with using CanvasJS as a global as long as you make sure it's included in the karma config.

An alternative path to explore is to look at Angular's e2e testing functionality. There's a bit of documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing). That might be a better fit when you're testing DOM rendering.

Comment: I tried to make some edit to my test controller but perhaps I miss something because the error is almost the same. I'll update my  question for a better code format.

Comment: Hm.. what happens if you initialize the controller before compiling and digesting the HTML fragment? If it still fails then I think looking at Protractor/e2e is a more viable approach.

Comment: Same :/. Protractor and e2e tests was already in the queue but before to do e2e tests shouldn't I do unit tests for the part of the controller that need it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think a e2e test should replace a unit test, but there are cases where some functionality just isn't suitable for unit tests. By including CanvasJS the controller is already not being tested in complete isolation. I'm not saying it is impossible to make this run in jasmine, but my goto-approach with $compile at least doesn't seem to work. There might be another way. If there are other functionality in the controller that is not directly canvas-related then providing a global mock implementation of CanvasJS could still let you test those parts in a unit test.

Comment: Could you please give some advice on how to mock an object for unit testing? I did some search but I did not find anything that explain well what has to be done.
If I want to mock the CanvasJS object just to get rid of the error message and then test the rest of the code, what do I have to do?

Are there any books or resources on the web that explain how to mock third party object?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Instead of accessing the CanvasJS constructor as a global (`new CanvasJS.Chart()` which btw is equivalent to `new window.CanvasJS.Chart()`) use Angular's `$window` service which wraps window. Now your code becomes `new $window.CanvasJS.Chart()`. Now you can pass a mock of `$window` to your controller, the same way you're already passing `$scope`to it.

Comment: I did it and update the question with the complete solution, thank you ivarni :)